# Laravel 5.4 Use If/Else inside of a controller

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to use @if & @else inside a controller, eg:

```
public function deleteCharacter ($char_delete_id)

    {

@if (Auth::user()->id == $delCharacterUserID) 
$deleteSuccess = 1;

            return redirect('/characters')->with('deleteSuccess', $deleteSuccess); 


@else 
      $deleteSuccess = 0;

        return redirect('/characters')->with('deleteSuccess', $deleteSuccess); 

    @endif
```

This throws the error:

> FatalErrorException in CharacterController.php line 40: syntax error,
>   unexpected 'if' (T_IF)

Comment: please take a quick look at the [php's if statement](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php) you are mixing between php syntax and blade syntax

Comment: you just use normal if(){...}else{...}   . i think @if for blade concept

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In a controller, just use the [normal PHP syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php), not [blade syntax](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade). So replace your code by:

```
public function deleteCharacter ($char_delete_id)
{
    if (Auth::user()->id == $delCharacterUserID) {
        $deleteSuccess = 1;

    } else {
        $deleteSuccess = 0;
    }
    return redirect('/characters')->with('deleteSuccess', $deleteSuccess);
}
```

And it should work! A controller is a PHP file, so write PHP in it.

Answer (score 2):

Optimize your code like that

```
 public function deleteCharacter ($char_delete_id)
    {
      $deleteSuccess = Auth::user()->id == $delCharacterUserID?1:0;      
      return redirect('/characters')->with('deleteSuccess', $deleteSuccess);
    }
```